# passing data from php to javascript problems with json_encode

Tags: php, mysql, json

I am kinda lost as to why I cant get data passed
javascript

```
jQuery.extend({
getValues: function(url) {
    var result = null;
    $.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: 'get',
    dataType: 'json',
    async: false,
    success: function(data) {

        result = JSON.stringify(data);

    }
return result;
```

I have no problems with the js part the problem is the php

```
$sql = "SELECT name, score FROM scores ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 10 ";
$result = mysqli_query($conn1, $sql);
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
$data = array(); 
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $data[] = array("name"=>$row['name'], "score"=>$row['score']);
    $post_data = json_encode(array($data));
}
echo $post_data;
}
```

echoing post data gives nothing if i echo post data inside while loop i get a result for every iteration of while loop. If i print_r data array i also get some kind of result. My question is what am i doing wrong?
Thank you for your answers I did bring out post data from the loop that was poorly made indeed however the real problem was that one of the names was in russian alphabet and the result from database wasnt utf-8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using [json_last_error](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php) I found that I couldnt encode because data wasn't utf-8

Answer (score 1):

Write `$post_data = json_encode(array($data));` after your while loop, otherwise you will be overwriting `$post_data` on each iteration.

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $data[] = array("name"=>$row['name'], "score"=>$row['score']);
}
$post_data = json_encode(array($data));
echo $post_data;
```

I don't expect this to solve your core problem, but you did ask "what am I doing wrong".

Let us know what you get with `var_export($data);` after the loop and before the `json_encode()`.  We need to see what that data & structure looks like.

Comment: @MM Do you really want to nest your `$data` in an array?  This is what is happening when you encode.  This is a demostration of what should be happening if your query is working properly. http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/9d820366d2c5bc0bdcfa8b2c3edcc04505b12eca

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
result = JSON.stringify(data);
```

For:

```
result = JSON.parse(data);
```